# CommandName doesnot work when I add Onclientclick on button control

Tags: jquery, winforms

jquery:

```
 function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
        alert("RowIndex: "+rowIndex);
        return false;
    }
```

asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="EmailSendbtn" Text="Send E-Mail" runat="server" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CommandName="SendEmail" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Directory")+","+ Eval("FirstFile")+","+ Eval("FirstFileDateModified")%>'    />
```

Not able to get to the Commandname method when I have added onClientClick. when I remove it, it works perfectly.
what to do? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: anyone please ?

Answer (score 0):

**simple way:--**

```js
function showMessage(msg) {
   alert(msg);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="showMessage('msgs');" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I need to do is use the rowindex to get something through commandname. This is why I have both the methods in the control